# Как сделать конструктор дочернего класса с параметрами базового класса для подсказки при вводе?

Tags: python, ооп, наследование, конструктор

Как сделать конструктор дочернего класса, чтобы исключить дублирование формальных параметров, но чтобы была подсказка по аргументам в конструкторе, при вводе дочернего класса в тексте.

Если сделать как у меня, то при вводе "Class2(" в подсказке выводится "*args, **kwargs", а как хотелось бы: "a, b, c, d, e".

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e):
        pass

class Class2(Class1):        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```